# Creating a related post section based on similar categories

Tags: php, categories

Heres my current code which is placed within my **single.php** file. It fetches tags. But I want to fetch categories instead. Can I just swap $tags with $categories.

```
        <div class="related-articles">
           <div class="related-articles-wrapper">

      <?php
            $orig_post = $post;
            global $post;
            $cats = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);

            if ($cats) {
            $cat_ids = array();
            foreach($cats as $individual_cat) $cat_ids[] = $individual_cat->term_id;
            $args=array(
            'category__in' => $cat_ids,
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'posts_per_page'=>3, // Number of related posts to display.
            'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
            );

            $my_query = new wp_query( $args );

            while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
              $my_query->the_post();
      ?>

<div class="posts__post" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'thumbnail'); ?> ) !important;">
                    <article>
                        <a class="posts__post--title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
                        <div class="posts__post--meta">
                          <p class="posts__post__tag"><a href=""><?php the_category('&nbsp;/&nbsp;'); ?></a></p>
                          <p class="posts__post__timestamp"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo time_ago(); ?></p>
                        </p>
                        </div>
                    </article>   
                </div>

                  <? }
                  }
                  $post = $orig_post;
                  wp_reset_query();
                  ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the Codex chapters which correspond to categories instead of tags:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

your code could be re-written to:

```
<?php
      $orig_post = $post;
      global $post;
      $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);

      if ($cats) {
      $cat_ids = array();
      foreach($cats as $individual_cat) $cat_ids[] = $individual_cat->term_id;
      $args=array(
      'category__in' => $cat_ids,
      'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
      'posts_per_page'=>3, // Number of related posts to display.
      'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
      );

      $my_query = new wp_query( $args );

      while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();
?>
```

Comment: Strange its not working :( I added HTML for full context. Looking through the codex now. Why use `wp_get_post_categories` ahead of  `get_the_category()`?

Comment: my mistake - `wp_get_post_categories()` already returns an array of category ids...so the code would need to  be adapted to that.
using `get_the_category()` might be preferrable.
 I have edited my reply accordingly.